# SQLSyntaxErrorException while creating a table, using Apache Derby

Tags: sql, derby, create-table

I have the following line of code in my project which uses Apache Derby:

```
 stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE table "+productName+" (Time FLOAT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, AcidNo FLOAT, Viscosity FLOAT, Temperature FLOAT)");
```

When the variable productName begins with a letter (ie "RedProduct"), everything works fine. When productName begins with a digit (ie "6Green"), the table *is* created, but I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "6" at line 1, column 15.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?? By the way, putting the table name in brackets did not help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting double quotes around the weird names?

```
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE table \"" + productName + 
    "\" (Time FLOAT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, AcidNo FLOAT, Viscosity FLOAT, Temperature FLOAT)");
```

Comment: So the quotes worked with "Create Table". But now I have another line stmt.executeQuery("select * from \"" + productName + "\" order by Time"). The double quotes do not work with table names which begin with a letter (even though this works with product names beginning with a number!). The error is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'Sample1' does not exist.

Comment: See [Rules for SQL92Identifiers](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/reference/sqlj10.html#HDRSQLJ1003454): ***"Delimited identifiers are identifiers surrounded by double quotation marks."***

Comment: And this [SQL92Identifier](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/reference/sqlj11.html#HDRSQLJ1004091) : ***"SQL92 identifiers are case-insensitive (unless delimited by double quotes)"***

Comment: So, my best advice would be to not use delimited identifiers, if you can. Perhaps you can add a default prefix (say `"t_"`) to all tables to avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and the reference link!